# Undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass in a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, collections, ruby-on-rails-4, partials

I am trying to display a collection as a partial ( on a side panel). I get an error above, have been fighting for several hours and do not understand what is the problem.

Containing view (a partial template included into application.html.haml file):

```
    %span.span12
      %ul.nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked{style: "color: white;"}
        = render :partial => 'categories/categories_list'
```

Partial /categories/_category_list.html.haml:

```
    %ul
      - @categories.each do |category|
        %li{style: "color: white;"}=category.name
```

Controller (categories_controller):

```
    class Macro::CategoriesController < ApplicationController

      def categories_list
        @categories= Category.all
      end
    end
```

I have separately tried to add "collection: @categories" as an option for render :partial - to non avail. When I replaced the instance variable with just an array in order to test the partial rendering, it worked ( the list items got rendered). Seem like the variable @categories does not get instantiated, however I have double-checked in console that a given activerecord query returns a set of objects.  I am breaking my brain to see where I made a mistake.

Log:

```
    Started GET "/ios/macro/namespace2/another" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-11 11:41:23 +0100
    Processing by Macro::Namespace2::AnotherController#index as HTML 
    Parameters: {"param1"=>"xx"}
    ....... (SQL queries for that view) 
    Rendered macro/namespace2/another_controller/_another_view.html.haml (7.0ms)
    Rendered macro/namespace2/another_controller/index.html.haml within layouts/application (29.6ms)
    Rendered layouts/_logout_link.html.haml (0.5ms)
    Rendered layouts/_top_navigation.html.haml (3.3ms)
    Rendered layouts/_search.html.haml (0.8ms)
    Rendered macro/categories/_categories_list.html.haml (0.8ms)
    Rendered macro/_navigation.html.haml (3.6ms)
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 49ms

    ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
        1: %ul
        2: - @categories.each do |category|
        3:   %li{style: "color: white;"}=category
    app/views/macro/categories/_categories_list.html.haml:2:in    `_app_views_macro_categories__categories_list_html_haml__246519878332953677_70248836672780'
    app/views/macro/_navigation.html.haml:11:in `_app_views_macro__navigation_html_haml__3071184578230019020_70248793690940'
    app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:24:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_haml__3208937943371424843_70248793607300'


    Rendered /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.1ms)
    Rendered /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.8ms)
    Rendered /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (10.6ms)
```

Routes:

```
        namespace "macro" do

          namespace "namespace2" do

            resources :another, only: [:index]
          end

        resources :categories
         end   
      end
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the `#categories_list` action in Macro::CategoriesController is not being called. Check the log and see which controller and action is handling the request.

You should see something like:

```
'Processing by Macro::CategoriesController#categories_list as HTML'
'Parameters: { }'
```

Comment: Yes, seems like that: I see the GET request that calls the containing view being processed by the corresponding controller. I do not even see any request when it tries to render the partial: `Rendered macro/_navigation.html.haml (1.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 49ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):` Is it possible to discover why exactly the request inside this partial (_navigation) that corresponds to `render :partial` does not get processed by the categories_controller?

Comment: Seeing that the controller action does not get called, I have tried to  put `render partial: 'categories_list' in the CategoriesController, also to no avail. Still do not understand, where is the disconnect?

Comment: update your post with your routes.rb file (just the relevant lines) and  include the request log

Comment: I have updated my question with the log and routing. I am not sure it is the routing error, because I have got routing error when I tried to change the path to the partial ( could not find controller :categories). In this case I do not get such an error.

Comment: rename the method #categories_list to #index. as I said in my original answer the method categories_list is not being called, index is called instead.

Comment: could you please help me understand the logic behind this? If you mean the processing of the original GET request, it is a completely different controller ("another_controller"), and the view index of this controller gets rendered. Inside it i have a partial layout , inside which i render the /_categories_list.html.haml partial which logically should correspond to an action of the following name? Where is the disconnect here?

Comment: There are 2 controllers at play here: **another_controller** (action #index, containing the partial view of  **categories_controller** (action #categories_list). The partial is to be displayed in many other views, besides just another_controller#index.